# Rank of $R$ in economic $QR$ decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

In an economic decomposition $A=QR$ of $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ - That is, $Q \in \mathbb{R} ^{m\times n}$ and $R \in \mathbb{R} ^{n\times n}$ and $m\geq n$, does $A$ being full rank imply $R$ being full rank? Or, if not, what is the connection between $rank(A)$ and $rank(R)$?

I know that $rank(A) = rank (A^T A)$, but I am not sure if it assists me in here.

Answer (score 1):

This can vary, depending on the notation of your book or paper, but generally speaking, $Q$ has an orthonormal basis of $Image(A)$ as its columns and $R$ corresponds to the coefficients of the linear combinations of the vectors of this basis so one obtains the columns of $A$.

We assume that $A$ has full column rank, i.e., its columns are linearly independent (LI), therefore dim($Image(A)$) = $n$. Simply employing the [Gramm-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), we see that since the columns of $A$ are LI, one needs to carry out full $n$ steps of the Gramm-Schmidt process in order to obtain a QR decomposition of $A$. Ending the process before the $n$-th step would necessarily mean that $Image(A) \neq Image(Q)$ (e.g. because the dimensions would be different), i.e., that columns of $Q$ do not form an orthonormal basis of $Image(A)$.

This in particular means that all of the diagonal elements in $R$ are nonzero because those correspond to the normalization and we have just shown that there will be $n$ steps of the Gramm-Schmidt process - hence also the normalization is done $n$ times.

Since $R$ is $n\times n$, is upper triangular and has nonzero diagonal it has rank $n$.

This *rank-revealing* also works in numerical computations, see, e.g., [papers on rank-revealing QR](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379587901030)

Comment: Could you elaborate why if $A$ is full rank then $R$ is full rank? The columns of $R$ are the coefficients of the linear combination of $Q$'s columns which give us the columns of $A$, but I do not see how $A$ being full rank implies these coefficients (in the columns of $R$) must be full rank as well?

Comment: I have editted the answer, hopefully it helps you to understand the matter.

Answer (score 0):

In the product of two matrices, the ranks of the factors are upper bounds for the rank of the product. Thus if $R$ had rank smaller than $n$, then also the rank of $A$ is smaller than $n$. Conversely, if $A$ has rank $n$, the rank of $R$ must be at least $n$. And as it can not be larger, it is $n$.